# How to add pop-box alike? c# vs2013

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, visual-studio-2013

I would like to improve my application's interface. Is it possible to add something like this(refer to image below)?:

[image]

When you click the name or move the cursor to the name, a pop up box will appear with user's main info. If possible, can you teach me the appropriate tools to use. I don't mind if it is basic tools, so i can make a little similar to the image.

BTW, i'm using visual studio 2013.

Comment: Try this one by [Lukasz Swiatkowski from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17502/Simple-Popup-Control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an (absolutely minimal) example of a pop-up `Panel` that takes care of the showing and hiding:

```
Panel popPanel = new Panel();

private void linkLabel1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    popPanel.Parent = linkLabel1.Parent;
    popPanel.Location = new Point(linkLabel1.Left -  20, linkLabel1.Top + 10);
    //popPanel.displayData(someDataClassFromSender);
    popPanel.Show();
    popPanel.MouseLeave += (ss, ee) => { popPanel.Hide(); };
}
```

For the layout and display of the info on the `Panel` (or some other control) you should create a class `PopUpPanel` and give it a method to load the data it shall display..

Answer (score -1):

If it is a web application go check out http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/fancy-navbar-login-sign-in-form

Just change the event from click to hover.

And get youserlf a copy of bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/